# django custom tag template -- date to words

Tags: python, django

I am trying to alter the date tag from

> 29 July

to

> TWENTYNINE JULY

This is how it is currently:

```
{{ article.publishing_date|date }}
```

Example of how to format:

```
{{ article.publishing_date|date:"F n, Y" }}
```

Other notes..

```
{% get_current_time "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p" as the_time %} 
<p>The time is {{ the_time }}.</p>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words

Comment: What is your question? what have you tried?

Comment: If the question is "How to do it?", the answer is actually in the two links you pointed.

Comment: Yes it would be something like this -- num2words(42, ordinal=True)
forty-second - and then a replace

Comment: would I split the date of the month as a separate var -- var day = {{ article.publishing_date|date:"d" }}

Comment: Not too sure how to install num2words in the django system

Comment: Well, as any other module. Something like `pip install num2words`.

Comment: yes - I am a bit wary of just doing a pip install on the build at this time - my first time working with django and python per say -- do I do anything like -- save dev - something like node?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip

Comment: yeah - its not a common python build -- using a docker with aldryn

Comment: If this is your issue, it should probably be mentioned in your question.

Comment: pip is not recognised in the aldyrn terminal